# product of common variables in two datasets

Tags: sas

```
data a1

a b c
2 3 4
1 2 3

data a2

a b  d
0 .3 1
0 .2 0


proc sql;
create table a3 as
select a.*, a.a * b.a + a.b * b.b as Value
from a1 a, a2 b;
```

There are many common columns in `a1` and `a2` (numeric columns with different values). I want to calculate `Value` as the 'sumproduct' of those common columns.

I try to avoid something like `a.common1 * b.common1 + a.common2 * b.common2 + ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few steps of preprocessing are needed as far as I can tell....

Load your data:

```
data a1 ;
input a b c ;
cards ;
2 3 4
1 2 3
;run ;

data a2 ;
input a b d ;
cards ;
0 0.3 1 
0 0.2 0
;run ;
```

Pull all variable names in A1 and A2 datasets (update your libname if required):

```
proc sql ;
create table data1 as
select libname, memname, name, label
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname= 'WORK' and memname in ('A1','A2')
    order by name
;quit ;
```

Keep only variables which are common to both datasets:

```
data data2 ;
  set data1 ;
  by name ;
  if last.name and not first.name ;
run ;
```

Put both a list and a count of the common variables into macro variables:

```
proc sql ;
select name
  into :commvarnames separated by ' ' 
  from data2
;
select count(name)
  into :commoncount
  from data2
;quit ;
```

Read in your source datasets - load the first, transfer them to a temporary array (therefore they do not overwrite the variable values) and then load the second dataset and do your calculations in a do loop:

```
data output ;
  set a1(keep=&commvarnames) ;  
  array one(&commoncount) _temporary_ ;
  array two(&commoncount) &commvarnames ;

  * Load A1 to temporary array ;
  do i=1 to &commoncount ;
    one(i)=two(i) ;
  end ;

  * Load A2 to variables ;
  set a2(keep=&commvarnames) ;  

  do i=1 to &commoncount ;
    product=sum(product,one(i)*two(i)) ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Comment: Yea, this seems to be a bit complicated then I thought. I should try to avoid such calculation using some pre-processing.

Answer (score 1):

It would take quite a bit of code to make this dynamic. I'd break it down like so:

- Get lists of the variables present in each dataset
- Merge the lists to get a list of the common variables
- Feed this into some array logic in a data step

Will post some code later, but hopefully that's enough to give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks. This really helps. It seems using array is inevitable.